# Txt record in DNS

Tags: dns, record

What is the purpose of having the txt dns record?  My web search found (many times) that it is also used to set up SPF, but I didn't find a site which explained the exact purpose of the txt record.  Any reference (especially on Stack Overflow) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TXT entries for several reasons

SPF : it will explicitly tell which servers (IP) are allowed to send email for your domain. As it is explicit, mail servers will trust mails incoming from IP you defined causing less spam consideration

DKIM : it's a security key to encrypt your email. The public key is obviously  public and stored in a TXT

You often use TXT entries also to prove that the domain belongs to you. Google apps verify that the domain you add belongs to you because you can correctly set a TXT record in your DNS zone. Another example is services like [LoadImpact](https://loadimpact.com/). This service will send a huge amount of connection to your domain, so you can DDOS almost any website with such a service. As a security they ask you to prove the domain your are testing is yours by adding a TXT value.

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

TXT records were just supposed to be used for "descriptive text".   From [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035):

> TXT RRs are used to hold descriptive text.  The semantics of the text
> depends on the domain where it is found.

Their (mis-)use by SPF, etc, to contain semi-structured data was unfortunate, and contrary to good design principles.

These days it's pretty easy to get a new RR type approved for application specific purposes.  (ObDisclaimer - I'm one of the four designated expert reviewers currently responsible for handling applications for new RR types as defined in [RFC 6895](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6895)).

Comment: RFC1464 "Using the Domain Name System To Store Arbitrary String Attributes" (May 1993) kind of specified how application could store data in TXT records using the key=value system. So unfortunately it is already at that date that the worm was in the fruit (even if the RFC is marked Experimental I am sure it gave ideas to others) leading to just the pure madness we have now with everything and the kitchen sink in `TXT` records instead of proper record types.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks for the pointer - I wasn't aware of that particular RFC.